# Missing methods and properties in _di_JXmlResourceParser

Tags: android, c++, xml, c++builder

I'm trying to use the _di_JXmlResourceParser object to access a XML file placed in `res\xml\`. I succeeded to open it with the following code :

```
_di_JXmlResourceParser parser = SharedActivityContext()->getAssets()
->openXmlResourceParser(StringToJString("res/xml/config.xml"));
```

But there's not all the methods listed in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html

The only methods proposed by C++Builder are the `getAttributeXXXX` methods and the method `close`, so I can't use the START_FLAG, getName, getEventType, getText needed to manipulate the object.

I tried to use `getAttribute` but it gives no result

```
UnicodeString result = JStringToString(parser->getAttribute(StringToJString("configuration"),
StringToJString("IPServeur")));
```

As the doc says, `getAttributeCount` only return me -1 then.

My includes :

```
#include <Androidapi.Helpers.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.Os.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp>
```

My XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <IPServeur>XXX</IPServeur>
    <PortServeur1>XXX</PortServeur1>
    <PortServeur2>XXX</PortServeur2>
    <PortServeurFTP1>XXX</PortServeurFTP1>
    <PortServeurFTP2>XXX</PortServeurFTP2>
    <UserNameFTP>XXX</UserNameFTP>
    <PasswordFTP>XXX</PasswordFTP>
    <LangueDefaut>XXX</LangueDefaut>
    <ActiveLog>XXX</ActiveLog>
    <NumeroSupport>XXX</NumeroSupport>
    <AdminPassword>XXX</AdminPassword>
</configuration>
```

Is my XML file wrong, did I just missed an include or is this class only partially translated by Embarcadero ?

Comment: `XmlResourceParser` implements multiple Java interfaces -  `XmlPullParser`, `AttributeSet`, and `AutoCloseable` - but Embarcadero's translation of `JXmlResourceParser` only implements the `JAttributeSet` interface. That is why you don't have access to all of the available methods. [You should report this bug to Embarcadero](http://quality.embarcadero.com), as it is likely a limitation of their Java2Pas convertor tool. As for your use of `getAttribute()`, it fails because you are dealing with XML node elements, not XML attributes.

Comment: In any case, `START_TAG` is a constant of `XmlPullParser`, so you wouldn't be able to access it via `JXmlResourceParser` anyway, you have to access it as `TJXmlPullParser::JavaClass->START_TAG` instead.

Comment: Hi, Remy. Thanks, I've just reported it to Embaracadero. I'm trying to find a way to read the updated config file of our app. The file was previously located in `.\assets\internal\ `, but is not upgraded to the new config file in the update apk, though it is shown as 'Always Replaced' in C++Builder Deployment manager, and seems to be due to Android itself. 
If not reading it directly, i'd like to store the InputStream that I can access. But I'm dealing problems with Java2OP, or direct usage of Java code in c++. Like creating a `_di_JFile ` with a new, the syntax is still not clear for me.